# How can I search through an array of objects for a unique id?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and a unique id. I'd like to search through the array of objects for the object instance that matches the unique id, but I'm not sure how to begin to approach it.

```
idToSearchfor = 2

arrayToBeSearched = [{content: 'string', id: 1}, {content: 'string', id: 2}, {content: 'string', id: 3}]
```

Comment: You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is for, assuming you're certain you will never have more than one matching item (`find` only returns the first matching item):

```js
let idToSearchfor = 2;

const arr = [{content: 'string', id: 1}, {content: 'string', id: 2}, {content: 'string', id: 3}]

console.log(arr.find(x=>x.id===idToSearchfor));
```

Otherwise (several possible matches), use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let idToSearchfor = 2;

const arr = [{content: 'string', id: 1}, {content: 'string', id: 2}, {content: 'string', id: 3}]

console.log(arr.filter(x=>x.id===idToSearchfor));
```

Comment: Thank you @connexo, can't believe I didn't know about this method until now!